# Taylor series about different points implies different interval of convergence?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm considering the taylor series of functions whose radius of convergence is non-infinite about different points, and I'm not sure if I'm interpreting this correctly.

Suppose, for concreteness, you are expanding $1/(1-x)$ about $x = 0$.  Then the series $1 + x + x^2 + ...$ is valid for $-1 < x < 1$.  Now suppose you are expanding it about $x = 100$.  You obtain $-1/99 * (1 - ((x-100)/99) + ...)$, which is valid for $-1 < (x-100)/99 < 1$.  But this means that the series is valid for $1 < x < 199$.

It seems to follow that by expanding about arbitrarily large values one can obtain a taylor series that is valid about an interval as large as one likes (that exclude the point -1.)  Is this correct?  Is this the reason for expanding about different points?  If so, why don't we more often see expansions about points very far from the point at which the function is undefined (since this will give us more information about the function) for functions whose taylor series has a finite radius of convergence?

Answer (score 2):

Taylor series of a function $f$ around a point $x_0$ are used mostly to describe the behavior of $f$ when $x$ is close to $x_0$. In that case the radius of convergence is not the most important thing. In your example the expansion around $x_0=0$
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^3+\dots
$$
tells you how $f$ behaves around $x_0=0$. For instance, you could use it to approximate $f(x)$ by a polynomial like $1+x+x^2+x^3$ (and also obtain a bound on he error.) In this case this does not seem very helpful, since you can calculate $f(x)$ directly. But what if $f(x)=\sin x$ for instance?

If you expand $f$ around $x_0=100$, you lose all the information about the behavior of $f$ at $0$, since the series will converge on $(1,199)$. On the other hand, you know a lot about how it behaves around $100$.

Comment: Was my general point correct, however?  That one can obtain a Taylor series for an interval (that excludes the singularities of the function) as large as one likes in cases like these?

Comment: The function $1/(1-x)$ goes kablooie at just one point, $x=1$. The Taylor series centered at $a$ will converge in the biggest interval (circle, in the complex plane) centered at $a$ and not including $x=1$. More generally, the radius of convergence will depend on the locations of the points where whatever function you are expanding goes kablooie.

Comment: So the answer is yes?

Comment: For cases like this, yes.